# Datediff performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff

I have a number of days variable which I want to compare against a datetime column (senddate).

I'm currently doing this:

```
DECLARE @RunDate datetime = '2013-01-01' 
DECLARE @CalculationInterval int = 10

DELETE
FROM TableA
WHERE datediff(dd, senddate, @RunDate) > @CalculationInterval
```

Anything that is older than 10 days should get deleted. We have Index on sendDate column but still the speed is much slower. I know the left side should not have calculation for performance reasons, but what is the optimal way of otherwise solving this issue?

Comment: how do I make the query "SARGable" in that case?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/799616/3205

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The expression

```
WHERE datediff(dd, senddate, @RunDate) > @CalculationInterval
```

won't be able to use an index on the `senddate` column, because of the function on the column  `senddate`

In order to make the `WHERE` clause 'SARGable' (i.e. able to use an index), change to the equivalent condition:

```
WHERE senddate < dateadd(dd, -@CalculationInterval, @RunDate)
```

[Thanks to @Krystian Lieber, for pointing out incorrect condition ].

Comment: I think the condition should be   
    WHERE senddate < dateadd(dd,  -@CalculationInterval, @RunDate) 
with the condition   
    WHERE senddate > dateadd(dd,  @CalculationInterval, @RunDate)
for @RunDate= '2013-01-11' and @CalculationInterval= 10 we delete all rows with senddate>'2013-01-21' when I think we would like to delete all rows with senddate<'2013-01-01'

Comment: @Krystian Lieber - Correct I already made that change on my end, just wanted to get an idea of how to make it sargable  :)

Comment: @Mitch Wheat can you correct that answer as per above suggestion and I will mark it as accepted?

Comment: I doesn't know that '-@var' = '-1*var'.
I learned two things on 1 answer :D thanks!